# No candidate version available for php7.4-fpm

Tags: linux, ubuntu, php-fpm, ubuntu-18.04

We’ve been installing `php7.4-fpm` via the `ppa:ondrej/php` repo with apt on an Ubuntu 18.04 server with our Chef recipes, but today it’s not working today. I think maybe the packages have been removed from the `ppa:ondrej/php` repo. Is there something I can do or maybe an alternative repo that can be used? We're trying to update the recipes and stack dependencies to work with PHP 8.x, but that won't work today. Today, I need to use `php7.4-fpm` unfortunately. Hoping someone might have some advice or know if/why these packages have been suddenly removed from the `ppa:ondrej/php` repo ‍♂️

Answer (score 0):

We had the same issue but in this case, using php8.0* packages on Ubuntu 18.04. In our case, we are using it on the Docker image so we change the Ubuntu base, jumping to 20.04 and it's working, but I don't know if it's helpful in your case.